# Best solution for SQL without looping

Tags: sql

I'm relatively new to SQL, and am trying to find the best way to attack this problem.

I am trying to take data from 2 tables and start merging them together to perform analysis on it, but I don't know the best way to go about this without looping or many nested subqueries.

What I've done so far:
I have 2 tables. Table1 has user information and Table2 has information on orders(prices and dates, as well as user)

What I need to do:
I want to have a single row for each user that has a summary of information about all of their orders. I'm looking to find the sum of prices of all orders by each user, the max price paid by that user, and the number of orders.  I'm not sure how to best manipulate my data in SQL.

Currently, my code looks as follows:

```
Select alias1.*, Table2.order_id, Table2.price, Table2.order_date
From (Select * from Table1 where country='United States') as alias1
LEFT JOIN Table2
on alias1.user_id = Table2.user_id
```

This filters out the datatypes by country, and then joins it with users, creating a record of each order including the user information.  I don't know if this is a helpful step, but this is part of my first attempt playing around with the data.  I was thinking of looping over this, but I know that is against the spirit of SQL

Edit: Here is an example of what I have and what I want:

Table 1(user info):

```
user_id    user_country
1          United States
2          United Kingdom
(etc)
```

Table 2(order info):

```
order_id    price    user_id
100         5.00     1
101         3.50     2
102         2.50     1
103         1.00     1
104         8.00     2
```

What I would like output:

```
user_id    user_country      total_price   max_price    number_of_orders
1          United States     8.50          5.00         3
2          United Kingdom    11.50         8.00         2
```

Comment: If you can define how the two tables should be related together, you can join them without looping.  Some sample data and desired output would be useful.  Also, what database are you using?

Comment: how about `select * from table1, table2 where table1.userid=table2.userid and table1.country="United States"`

Comment: Also, if you can more concretely define what "*single row for each user that has a summary of information about all of their orders*" means we can probably show you how to do it pretty easily.

Comment: DON'T USE LOOPS IN SQL!  Explain exactly what you need and we can show you how to do it, many times faster.

Comment: For example, I want the total sum of all prices from orders for a particular user, or the largest price paid by a user out of all their users.  I'm updating a sample of what I have and the format I want it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do this:

```
SELECT    alias1.user_id, 
          MAX(alias1.user_name) As user_name,
          SUM(Table2.price)     As UsersTotalPrice,
          MAX(Table2.price)     As UsersHighestPrice
FROM      Table1                As alias1
LEFT JOIN Table2    ON alias1.user_id = Table2.user_id
WHERE     country   = 'United States'
GROUP BY  user_id
```

If you can give us the actual table definitions, then we can show you some actual working queries.

Comment: This is excellent, thank you! I didn't think to put those sum and max statements directly into the select statement.  Does the line "GROUP BY user_id" affect the SUM and MAX functions?

Comment: MAX(alias1.user_name)? are you sure? I would not use this, I would put username in group by

Comment: @halfbit2 That works too, but this is generally faster (slightly) and since `user_name` is functionally determined by `user_id` (presumably), it's just as or even more correct than adding spurious `GROUP BY` columns.

Comment: @user3022606 Yes, aggregate functions like `MAX`, and `SUM` are only over their current group-by key values.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Thanks again! I still have a way to go into understanding the inner workings of sql, but this has helped a lot. Thanks for the offer of working queries, but I think I will manage on my own.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I can remember when I was learning SQL, my DBAs allways confused me with such (performance) 'tricks', I wanted to understand the basics, but they where realy good DBAs ... I had a hard learning curve, but sure - you are right (like DBAs always are ;-) (no kidding)

Comment: @RBarryYoung Your suggestion is spot on and works like a charm!  I had one final question I wanted to implement.  What if I only want to display a cutoff of the `UsersTotalPrice`, for example, if I only wanted to filter out those who spent a total of more than $10?  I figured i could add an `AND` clause to the `WHERE` portion, but it didn't seem to work.  My naive attempt was `WHERE country = 'United States' AND UsersTotalPrice > 10`, and I get an invalid column name error.  I'm assuming the `UsersTotalPrice` I created with the group by hasn't resolved, or isn't accessed in this manner

Comment: @RBarryYoung Well, I discovered the `HAVING` keyword for this situation, and used the equivalent of `HAVING SUM(Table2.price) > 10` after the `GROUP BY` statement.  Not sure if this is the best method, but it worked!

Comment: @mrdst `HAVING`, though rarely used, is intended for just that situation.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Agregate the rows in table2 and then join to table 1 for the detail info you want?

```
SELECT Table1.*,agg.thesum FROM
(SELECT UserID, SUM(aggregatedata) as thesum FROM Table2 GROUP BY UserID)  agg
 INNER JOIN Table1 on table1.userid = agg.userid
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
select table1.*, t2.total_price, t2.max_price, t2.order_count
```

from table1
join (selectt user_id, sum(table2.price) as total_price, max(table2.price) as max_price, count(order_id) as order_count from table2 as t2 group by t2.user_id)
on table1.user_id = t2.user_id
where t1.country = 'untied_states'

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: (removed:"dont use explicit join" this was wrong, I meant:)
Try to use the following Sytax, for better understanding what goes on:

1st step:

```
select 
    user.user_id,   -- < you must tell the DB userid of which column
    user_country,
    price, 
    price 
from -- now just the two tables:
    Table1 as user, --table1 is a bad name, we use 'user'
    Table2 as order
where user.user_id = order.user_id
```

so you will get somthing like:

```
user_id    user_country    price    price 
1          alabama         5        5
2          nebrasca        1        1
2          alabama         7        7
1          alabama         7        7
2          alabama         3        7
```

and so on ..

the next step is to add an other `where usercountry='alabama'` so 'nebrasca' is off

```
user_id    user_country    price    price 
1          alabama         5        5
2          alabama         7        7
1          alabama         7        7
2          alabama         3        7
```

now you are ready for "aggregate": just select the MAX and SUM of price, but you have to tell the SQL engine what columes are 'fixed' = group by

```
select 
   user.user_id, user_country, MAX(price), SUM(price) 
from 
    Table1 as user, 
    Table2 as order
where user.user_id = order.user_id
and user_country='alabama'
group by user_id, user_country
```

Comment: "*First try to not use (explicit) join*", Uhmm, No.  Explicit join syntax is *highly* preferred, both in practice and by the SQL standards.  Implicit joins have been supported but obsolete for over 20 years, and are so specifically because in the judgement of the industry and profession they are *harder* to read.  They *should not be used*.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: he/she is learning (or seems to), I tried to get back to the roots, but you are right, my Intro is "wrong" i try to re formulate.